# Remote debugging Rails application using RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I'm following the instructions listed in the 
[Remote debugging article published by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging.html) to debug a remote Rails application using RubyMine.

Based on the instructions, I'm supposed to run

```
rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 ? bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

on the remote host. Running the above command throws the following error message stating that option -b is invalid.

```
-bash-4.1$ rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0  bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0 
    Using ruby-debug-base 0.2.1 Usage: rdebug-ide is supposed to be called from RDT, NetBeans, RubyMine, or
               the IntelliJ IDEA Ruby plugin.  The command line interface to
               ruby-debug is rdebug.

        Options:
            -h, --host HOST                  Host name used for remote 

debugging
        -p, --port PORT                  Port used for remote debugging
            --dispatcher-port PORT       Port used for multi-process debugging dispatcher
            --evaluation-timeout TIMEOUT evaluation timeout in seconds (default: 10)
            --stop                       stop when the script is loaded
        -x, --trace                      turn on line tracing
        -l, --load-mode                  load mode (experimental)
        -d, --debug                      Debug self - prints information for debugging ruby-debug itself
            --xml-debug                  Debug self - sends information <message>s for debugging ruby-debug itself
        -I, --include PATH               Add PATH to $LOAD_PATH
            --attach-mode                Tells that rdebug-ide is working in attach mode
            --keep-frame-binding         Keep frame bindings
            --disable-int-handler        Disables interrupt signal handler
            --rubymine-protocol-extensions
                                         Enable all RubyMine-specific incompatible protocol extensions
            --catchpoint-deleted-event   Enable chatchpointDeleted event
            --value-as-nested-element    Allow to pass variable's value as nested element instead of attribute

    Common options:
        -v, --version                    Show version

    invalid option: -b
```

- RubyMine version 2017.1
- Remote Host OS: Centos-6.9
- Ruby version: 2.3.1p112

Could you please help me to understand what's going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the command you are using is incorrect. It should be:

```
rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

You have a missing double dash before bin/rails.

The error says the b option is not valid for the rdebug-ide command. However, the b option is intended for the bin/rails s command.

Comment: Doesn't work with the dash as well. Same error "invalid option: -b".

Comment: I tried with double dash. It's trying to load a file in the current directory when the local debugger connects to it and it fails.

-bash-4.1$ rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 ? -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta4, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1236
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file --

Could you please let me know on what it's expecting? Pardon my ignorance as I'm new to Rails. Thank you.

Comment: Can you supply the exception details please?

Comment: Should there be a "?" also before the double dash?

If I ignore the "?", I'm still getting the same error (invalid option -b). But if I use following command 

rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 ? -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0

it starts up but when the debugger connects, it throws the exception

Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- /vagrant/abc/webservices/xyz/?
 /var/imno/external/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
 /var/mno/external/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'

I guess it's trying to load some file from the current directory and it's failing